# Android. Error when retrieve data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase realtime database. Here is my code:

```
   firebaseDatabase.reference.child("newsList").get().addOnSuccessListener { dataSnapshot ->
            firebaseCallback.onResult(Result.success(MainContentModel(dataSnapshot.children.mapNotNull { it.getValue(NewsModel::class.java) }, emptyList())))
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            firebaseCallback.onResult(generateErrorResult(it))
        }
```

But I can't get the data, instead I get the error.

> java.lang.Exception: Client is offline

The version I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.0'
```

The data structure looks like this:

[image: Data structure]

I also tried:

```
setPersistenceEnabled(true)
```

But it didn't work for me:(

***NOTE:*** I have a good internet connection

Please help me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So are you sure you have internet connection on user device?

Comment: @Alex Mamo, yes!